# review output log file

Tags: batch-file

I have a log file with output of command in my batch file.
I want to review on this file and check if there were an error.
this is the row of this file with error:

> 9/20/2012 7:22:34 AM   [Error] Error occured while reloading resource table: VALUE is duplicated

how I can to check it?
I try the following:

```
for /f "tokens=4 %%x in (%TMPLog%) do 
    if "%%x"=="ERROR" SET err=TRUE
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have that much easier:

```
findstr /l /c:"[Error]" "%TMPLog%" >nul 2>&1 && set err=1
```

Another random note: For boolean variables I tend to have the pattern of the variable being defined when it's true and not defined when it's false. Then you can simply check it with `if defined err` which reduces errors from mistyping the comparison value and also works properly in blocks without delayed expansion (another common source of mistakes). Just if you were wondering why I used `set err=1` instead of `set err=TRUE`.

Comment: +1 - You might prefer to redirect the output of FINDSTR to nul since there is no need to see the output.

Comment: Eep, indeed. Thanks :) ... And somehow it's always the same four people frequenting batch file questions :D

Comment: @zipi You might want to read [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php). In short, most batch programs use 2 output streams: #1 is the `stdout` (standard output) and #2 is the `stderr` (error messages), and everything is written to the console by default. Thus, if you redirect stream #1 to `nul`, it won't be displayed on the console, but the error message will be! `2>&1` basically redirects stream #2 (the error messages) to #1's destination, which is `nul` in this case -- meaning that #2 here won't be displayed as well.

Answer (score 2):

Joey provided the simplest solution to your problem. But he did not explain why your code does not work.

The entire DO clause must be on one line unless parens are used.

```
for /f ... do ...
```

or

```
for /f .... do (
   ...
)
```

Your search criteria is also flawed.

You can either fix the string you are looking for:

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%x in (%TMPLog%) do if "%%x"=="[ERROR]" SET err=TRUE
```

Or you can fix the location where you are looking for it:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%x in (%TMPLog%) do if "%%x"=="ERROR" SET err=TRUE
```

But I still recommend Joey's FINDSTR solution over any FOR based solution.

Comment: I missed the tokenizing due to missing formatting initially, too. I understood it like they just compared the first token to `"ERROR"` which sounded very unlike what they were trying. So my first reaction was "Just give them `findstr`  and be done with it than trying to explain lengthily why the `for` won't work" ;)

Comment: I believe you're missing a double quote in each example. ;)